# как добавить второй GET параметр из input в URL

Tags: php

Как можно передать второй параметр GET из input?

кнопка передаёт значение, но затирает предыдущие get параметры в строке:

```
<form method="GET" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <span class="input-group-text">Введите возраст</span> 
    <input type="number" value="25" min="18" max="99" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="age" >
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Отфильтровать возраст">
</form>
```

Также есть кнопка которая добавляет параметр без затирания предыдущих

```
<a href="?<?= http_build_query(array_merge($_GET , ['city' => $currentcity])); ?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Показать из моего города <?php echo $currentcity ?> </a>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на первую кнопку get параметр также добавлялся к уже имеющимся?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете добавить нужные скрытые поля input в вашу форму, с значениями из массива $_GET.
Например:

```
<form method="GET" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <span class="input-group-text">Введите возраст</span>
    <? foreach ($_GET as $name => $value) { ?>
        <? if ($name === 'age') continue; ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="<?=$name?>" value="<?=$value?>">
    <? } ?>
    <input type="number" value="25" min="18" max="99" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="age" >
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Отфильтровать возраст">
</form>
```

Comment: Работает, но если нажать второй раз, то параметр добавляется в урл ещё раз: localhost/search.php?age=32&age=22

Comment: Отредактировал сообщение